# in how many languages /* ........... */ work as a comment? Other than CSS

Tags: c, css, programming-languages, comments

in how many languages `/* ........... */` work as a comment? other than CSS

Comment: SQL, Java... this should be community wiki.

Comment: Most languages that are descended from C

Comment: Other than CSS? For me that is a C style comment. Not a CSS style comment...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Sure about SQL? I thought only -- was standardized.

Comment: Thilo: TSQL at least--used it earlier today.

Comment: Oracle, too. Probably everyone these days. According to Wikipedia, it is a TSQL extension. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_%28computer_programming%29#SQL

Comment: Certainly more than just Oracle and TSQL (Sybase, MS SQL Server); Informix for one more.

Comment: @Michael: the answer must be 42!

Comment: @Thilo @Jonathon Leffler Confirmed MySQL (5.1.49), and Pervasive (v8)

Comment: 42... I love it!  It never gets old :)

Comment: 42 can be derived from two thirteen (13 + 1) * 3 - hence I guess its okay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking the list on Wikipedia as a starting point:

- ActionScript
- AutoHotkey
- C
- CHILL
- C++
- C#
- CSS
- D
- Go
- Java
- JavaScript
- J++
- J#
- Objective C
- Objective C++
- PHP
- PL/I
- PL/SQL
- REXX
- SAS
- Scala
- SQL
- TSQL
- Visual Prolog

and probably others too...

Comment: And does it works same in all like it works in CSS. in multiple or single lines code.?

Comment: This the list on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)#Block_comments

Comment: You can make it work in Perl, too. ;-)

Comment: @Richard Cook: J# is yet another one :)

Comment: @Michael Mao: and who could forget J++? ;-)

Comment: @Thilo: Yo ucan make anything work in Perl. :-)

Answer (score 2):

All C-based languages for a start.